# 3 columns vertically center in a row Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) in a static website. In the footer I have 3 columns `col-lg-4` in a row.

My footer looks like:

[image: screenshot]

What I need is center of the row with 3 columns like below:

[image: screenshot]

This is my code:

```html
<!-- libraries for demo: -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- actual code: -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a>Sub Menu</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeysinghanbu/wgm2zp9e/2/)

Comment: Have a look at col offset - allows you to specifiy dummy columns before actual columns to give you what you need

Comment: This is what you are looking for I guess: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns. If not, try adding margin: auto; to the outer div (with the row class, that wraps the columns)

Comment: @Bram Was it a recursion of questions? :)

Comment: Oops, did not notice that haha. My bad. Just fixed the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well if your columns are each 2 bootstrap-columns wide you could use the following:

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-3">
  Menu 1
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  Menu 2
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
  Menu 3
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @MY1. This Answer sloved my Problem :)

Comment: no problem.essentially the grid in BS exists of 12 cols and with offset you, well add on offset and dividing 12 by 2x3 (6, the total width of your cols) we have 6 left, divide that by 2 and you have your offset, but be reminded that the offset can only be an integer, so it doesnt work everywhere.